# session timeout issue using ajax

Tags: javascript, spring, session, timeout

I have 2 application one in struts and other one is in spring. From struts application I have one link which will call spring application controller through ajax call which returns **model**.

In struts application I have session timeout for 20 mins and while doing any transaction for the spring application which is rendered in the struts application the session timeout in struts application remains same and after 20 mins it is logging out.

struts application jsp page.

```
    <body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
         var sessionId = '<%= sessionId %>'

         $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '/springapp/index.app?id='+sessionId,
         data: "" ,
        success: function(response){
            $('#content').html(response);
        },
        error: function(e){
        alert('Error: ' + e);
        console.log(e)
        }
    });


    });
</script>
```

Spring application controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*.app", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String jspController(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws exception {
        LOGGER.debug("inside jspController() start");
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String model = request.getRequestURI();
        if (model.endsWith("index.app")) {
            String sessionKey = request.getParameter("employeeId");
            SpringStrutsHandshake springStrutsHandshake = securityDelegate.getUserId(sessionKey);
            User user = userDelegate.getUserByEmployeeId(springStrutsHandshake.getUserId());
            user.setSessionKey(sessionKey);
            request.setAttribute("USER", user);
            model = "candidateList";
        } else {
            model = model.substring(model.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, model.lastIndexOf("."));
        }
        return model;
    }
```

could you please help me how to fix timeout issue when there is any transaction in the rendered spring applicaiton page?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the session timeout in struts application, why don't you just keep sending requests periodically(maybe every 15 mins) to the struts app which does nothing but just to keep the session from idling, until spring app calls back.

Or you can add a method to dynamically set the session timeout time like this

```
request.getSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60); //in seconds
```